# combining two sqldf statements

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, sqldf

I've been trying for all day now. Can somebody help me combine below queries. I am getting the desired result with below, but I understand it should be done in one.

```
moo<-sqldf('SELECT id, count(id) AS idcount 
           FROM MyData WHERE id IS not null 
           GROUP BY id')
sqldf("SELECT id, idcount  FROM moo 
       WHERE idcount = (SELECT min(idcount) FROM moo)")
```

Comment: "sql" is a language, but implemented differently by every db vendor, so when asking sql related questions **always** include what dbms it is for

Comment: @Used_By_Already since the code has default settings in sqldf statement in R, it should be a SQLite dbms

Comment: OK, see [WITH clause](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer will depend on the database receiving the SQL, without `with` you have to repeat the "moo" query

```
  SELECT id, idcount  
  FROM (
       SELECT id, count(id) AS idcount 
       FROM MyData WHERE id IS NOT NULL 
       GROUP BY id 
       ) moo 
  WHERE idcount = (
    SELECT min(idcount) 
    FROM (
       SELECT id, count(id) AS idcount 
       FROM MyData WHERE id IS NOT NULL 
       GROUP BY id 
       ) 
  OR idcount = (
    SELECT max(idcount) 
    FROM (
       SELECT id, count(id) AS idcount 
       FROM MyData WHERE id IS NOT NULL 
       GROUP BY id 
       )
```

and you may be better off doing this in your code than in SQL

IF the dbms does support [WITH](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html), then:

```
  WITH moo AS (  
  SELECT id, idcount  
  FROM (
       SELECT id, count(id) AS idcount 
       FROM MyData WHERE id IS NOT NULL 
       GROUP BY id 
       ) 
    )
  SELECT id, idcount  
  FROM moo
  WHERE idcount = (
    SELECT min(idcount) 
    FROM moo)
  OR idcount = (
    SELECT max(idcount) 
    FROM moo)
```

Comment: WITH moo AS "(" this bracket wasn't closed off, but the code was perfect. Gracias!

Comment: Sorry, just fixed that. Thanks for picking that up. Cheers.

Comment: Ok so just like min(idcount) I need a max(idcount) as well, is it possible to incorporate that in this query.

Comment: Yes, I have edited the answer for both min and max, basically just an OR condition within the where clause

Comment: That is just so pretty.